# sfdx command cannot be found even after the path has been added into system path

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

After installing sfdx cli tool in my machine (My IT department helped with that since I don't have admin access), the related path doesn't seem to get automatically installed. So I added that myself. However, after that, it still doesn't seem to work in other directories:

[image]

Any reason why this is not working?

Comment: Have you relaunched the CMD since you added to the PATH variable?

Comment: @pchittum actually I have only added into the cmd's path.

Comment: You'll need to relaunch the command line in order for the updated PATH to be loaded and recognized. Then you should be good.

Comment: @pchittum Actually I have only added the path into the cmd's path context. I have also try reloading though...